# Activate PHP Session when click on a link

Tags: php, session, hyperlink, onclick

right now my php session loads when I load the page. The code looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['started'] = true;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>First page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="WHEN CLICK ON THIS LINK I WANT THE PHP SESSION TO START">LINK</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is instead of the PHP session loads when the page loads I want it to load when the user clicks on the link.

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if you make an ajax call to a page that starts the session. However, what's the point? The session won't work in the current page unless it also calls session_start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(isset($_GET['link'])) {
    $_SESSION['started'] = true;
}
?>

<a href="?link"> LINK </a>
```

Comment: Cool - but what if I want to send the user to a new page and start the session. And that both of the things happen when i click on the link?

Comment: you can do that by determining if the user has clicked on the link. for example you can define an anchor tag which redirects to another page `<a href="anotherpage.php?link"> LINK </a>` and in anotherpage.php define the same condition (with reference to my answer) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['session'])) {
    session_start(); 
     $_SESSION['started'] = true;

}
?>

<a href="?session=1">LINK</a>
```

This reloads the whole page, an AJAX call would be much better